# Webcam works with cheese, but not in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webcam, ubuntu-14.04

I have a HP dv7t-6c00 running Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. The webcam works when I try it from cheese, but when I try it from Chrome at webcamtoy.com all I get is a black picture.

In chrome I select "Use my camera" and click on "Allow". A white light comes on from my webcam. When I click the button to take the picture all I get is black. The light stays on constantly and doesn't flash.

The webcam worked fine from Chrome when I had Win7 installed as a native OS, so I know the hardware is OK. What do I have to do to get the webcam to work from chrome in Ubuntu?

Comment: Reproduced this problem with firefox and opera.  Filed a bug:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1416187

Comment: I was able to get the webcam to work in chrome using http://snapshot.htmlchat.net/.  I got a dialog from Flash where I clicked Allow and then clicked Allow at the top of Chrome.  Something is still wrong if it depends on the website.

Comment: To the person who deleted my second post - that was the answer.  I'll repost and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be a problem with the [webcamtoy.net](http://webcamtoy.net) website.  My webcam worked at [www.testwebcam.com](http://www.testwebcam.com) and [snapshot.htmlchat.net](http://snapshot.htmlchat.net), but not at [webcamtoy.com](http://webcamtoy.com).